# how to do 'any(::text[]) ilike ::text'

Tags: postgresql, conditional-statements, string-comparison, any

here is table structure

```
table1
pk int, email character varying(100)[]

data
1, {'mr_a@gmail.com', 'mr_b@yahoo.com', 'mr_c@postgre.com'}
```

what i try to achieve is find any 'gmail' from record

```
query
select * from table1 where any(email) ilike '%gmail%';
```

but *any()* can only be in left-side and *unnest()* might slow down performance. anyone have any idea?

*edit*

actually i kinda confuse a bit when i first post. i try to achieve through *any(array[])*.

this is my actual structure

```
pk int, 
code1 character varying(100), 
code2 character varying(100), 
code3 character varying(100), ...
```

my first approch is

```
select * from tabl1 where code1 ilike '%code%' or code2 ilike '%code%' or...
```

then i try

```
select * from table1 where any(array[code1, code2, ...]) ilike '%code%'
```

which is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an operator that implements `ILIKE` "backwards", e.g.:

```
CREATE FUNCTION backward_texticlike(text, text) RETURNS booleans
    STRICT IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL
    AS $$ SELECT texticlike($2, $1) $$;

CREATE OPERATOR !!!~~* (
    PROCEDURE = backward_texticlike,
    LEFTARG = text,
    RIGHTARG = text,
    COMMUTATOR = ~~*
);
```

(Note that `ILIKE` internally corresponds to the operator `~~*`.  Pick your own name for the reverse.)

Then you can run

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE '%code%' !!!~~* ANY(ARRAY[code1, code2, ...]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Store email addresses in a normalized table structure. Then you can avoid the expense of `unnest`, have "proper" database design, and take full advantage of indexing. If you're looking to do full text style queries, you should be storing your email addresses in a table and then using a [tsvector datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-textsearch.html) so you can perform full text queries AND use indexes. `ILIKE '%whatever%'` is going to result in a full table scan since the planner can't take advantage of any query. With your current design and a sufficient number of records, `unnest` will be the least of your worries.

**Update** Even with the updates to the question, using a normalized codes table will cause you the least amount of headache and result in optimal scans. Anytime that you find yourself creating numbered columns, it's a good indication that you might want to normalize. That being said, you can create a computed text column to use as a search words column. In your case you could create a `search_words` column that is populated on insert and update by a trigger. Then you can create a `tsvector` to build full text queries on the `search_words`

Comment: thanks for suggestion. actually i'm Thai. The db data is in thai language and full-text search work terribly in Thai language due to words and language complexity are totally different from Eng. I've try your solution and it's great in Eng. But when i try it in Thai it doesn't work well. Your db optimizing suggestion really helps.